# Find Non-exhaustive pattern

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

Can i somehow see what pattern haskell tries to use?
It works on the smaller example, but crashes on the larger one, and I have a hard time finding what case it could be.

```
euler18 :: [[Integer]]
euler18 = pathPyr minipyr

pathPyr xss = path [(head xss)] (tail xss)

minipyr = [[3],[7,4],[2,4,6]]
pyramid = [[75], [95,64], [17,47,82], [18,35,87,10], [20,4,82,47,65], [19,1,23,75,3,34], [88,2,77,73,7,63,67], [99,65,4,28,6,16,70,92], [41,41,26,56,83,40,80,70,33], [41,48,72,33,47,32,37,16,94,29], [53,71,44,65,25,43,91,52,97,51,14], [70,11,33,28,77,73,17,78,39,68,17,57], [91,71,52,38,17,14,91,43,58,50,27,29,48], [63,66,4,68,89,53,67,30,73,16,69,87,40,31], [4,62,98,27,23,9,70,98,73,93,38,53,60,4,23]]

path :: [[Integer]] -> [[Integer]] -> [[Integer]]
path xss (ys:[])  = extendpath xss ys
path xss (ys:yss) = path (extendpath xss ys) yss

extendpath :: [[Integer]] -> [Integer] -> [[Integer]]
extendpath (xs:[]) (y1:y2:[]) = [y1:xs,y2:xs]
extendpath (xs:xss) (y1:y2:ys) = [y1:xs,y2:xs] ++ extendpath xss (y2:ys)
```

the output:

```
*Main> pathPyr pyramid 
[[4,63,91,70,53,41,41,99,88,19,20,18,17,95,75],[62,63,91,70,53,41,41,99,88,19,20,18,17,95,75],[62,66,91,70,53,41,41,99,88,19,20,18,17,95,75],[98,66,91,70,53,41,41,99,88,19,20,18,17,95,75],[98,66,71,70,53,41,41,99,88,19,20,18,17,95,75],[27,66,71,70,53,41,41,99,88,19,20,18,17,95,75],[27,4,71,70,53,41,41,99,88,19,20,18,17,95,75],[23,4,71,70,53,41,41,99,88,19,20,18,17,95,75],[23,4,71,11,53,41,41,99,88,19,20,18,17,95,75],[9,4,71,11,53,41,41,99,88,19,20,18,17,95,75],[9,68,71,11,53,41,41,99,88,19,20,18,17,95,75],[70,68,71,11,53,41,41,99,88,19,20,18,17,95,75],[70,68,52,11,53,41,41,99,88,19,20,18,17,95,75],[98,68,52,11,53,41,41,99,88,19,20,18,17,95,75],[98,89,52,11,53,41,41,99,88,19,20,18,17,95,75],[73,89,52,11,53,41,41,99,88,19,20,18,17,95,75],[73,89,52,11,71,41,41,99,88,19,20,18,17,95,75],[93,89,52,11,71,41,41,99,88,19,20,18,17,95,75],[93,53,52,11,71,41,41,99,88,19,20,18,17,95,75],[38,53,52,11,71,41,41,99,88,19,20,18,17,95,75],[38,53,38,11,71,41,41,99,88,19,20,18,17,95,75],[53,53,38,11,71,41,41,99,88,19,20,18,17,95,75],[53,67,38,11,71,41,41,99,88,19,20,18,17,95,75],[60,67,38,11,71,41,41,99,88,19,20,18,17,95,75],[60,67,38,33,71,41,41,99,88,19,20,18,17,95,75],[4,67,38,33,71,41,41,99,88,19,20,18,17,95,75],[4,30,38,33,71,41,41,99,88,19,20,18,17,95,75],[23,30,38,33,71,41,41,99,88,19,20,18,17,95,75]*** Exception: euler18.hs:(16,1)-(17,72): Non-exhaustive patterns in function Main.extendpath
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have tons and tons of cases that aren't covered.  This means that you have partial functions, which are **bad**.  Try to avoid them as much as possible.  Often, it's easy to convert them into total functions using the `Maybe` type constructor.  Then you can use pattern matching to make sure all cases are covered.  Also, note that `head` and `tail` are partial functions.

As a hack to diagnose this, I'd just add something like:

```
extendPath xs ys = error ("oops, pattern-match failed, arguments were: " ++ show xs ++ show ys)
```

Make sure that that case goes *after* the other ones, because it's a catch-all.

You'll have to do this for `path` and `pathPyr`, too.  You may want to recruit Haskell's help by turning on warnings.

Comment: Thank you! I know it is partial but since i know the structure i don't have to have all cases. Although obviously it seems like some case was missed

Comment: @Vixen not to sound glib, but if you know the structure then why was a case missed?  Help Haskell help you -- use its awesome type system to find the errors for you!

Answer (score 5):

```
extendpath :: [[Integer]] -> [Integer] -> [[Integer]]
extendpath (xs:[]) (y1:y2:[]) = [y1:xs,y2:xs]
extendpath (xs:xss) (y1:y2:ys) = [y1:xs,y2:xs] ++ extendpath xss (y2:ys)
```

While it works, `extendpath` *doubles* the number of paths each time it's called. But the length of the rows increases only by 1. So as soon as you have a triangle with more than three rows, you get a pattern-match failure when processing the fourth (and every later) row.

After the second (zero-based, so the row with three elements) row, you have

```
--          LL   LR   RL   RR
extendpath [p_1, p_2, p_3, p_4] [v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4]
~> [v_1:p_1, v_2:p_1] ++ extendpath [p_2, p_3, p_4] [v_2, v_3, v_4]
~> [v_1:p_1, v_2:p_1] ++ [v_2:p_2, v_3:p_2] ++ extendpath [p_3, p_4] [v_3, v_4]
~> [v_1:p_1, v_2:p_1] ++ [v_2:p_2, v_3:p_2] ++ [v_3:p_3, v_4:p_3] ++ extendpath [p_4] [v_4]
```

and the last call has no matching pattern.

Now, the paths `p_2` and `p_3` end in the same place, so the two can be extended by the same two values in the next row, but `extendpath` doesn't take into account where a path ends. Generally, on the `n`-th row there are

```
n `choose` k
```

paths ending in the `k`-th spot [that's why I chose zero-based counting here]. When extending paths, the possible extensions depend on the current end point of the path.

You need a different approach. Especially for problem 67.

Answer (score 2):

You can make GHC/GHCi give you a warning when there's incomplete patterns by giving `-W` as an argument to GHC, or entering `:set -W` in GHCi (and recompiling/reloading your file!).

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.  The OP already knows the functions have incomplete patterns, but doesn't know when/what exactly triggers the error.

Comment: @MattFenwick: I only saw Vixens comment on your answer after I had posted mine! There's also something to be said for preventing the error instead of patching up the symptoms...

Answer (score 2):

A good error warning level would give you all the info you need. To trigger it, put in the head of your files:

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}
```

This will warn you about a bunch of other stuff too, most probably. Which is good.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.  The OP already knows the functions have incomplete patterns, but doesn't know when/what exactly triggers the error.

Comment: Yup it doesn't exactly gives the info OP asks for. It IMHO gives the info the OP needs, aka stick to a good error level and listen to what GHC tells you since if you do you won't encounter the problem in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Another option to catch missing patterns:

http://community.haskell.org/~ndm/catch/